# Maximizing image size, centering, and fitting columns around it

Tags: html, css

I have a program using server side rendering to create simple HTML:
A lightbox containing:

- Buttons for tabbing through a sideshow
- A single gallery infobox (classes gal-info and infobox)
- A slideshow of pairs of

  - an image (class photo but my rules are just assigned to `.lbox img`) and an info table  (classes img-exif and infobox)

I'm unsure where to place the buttons, everything else should be rendered left to right in that order, with vertical centering, maximizing the side of the image (I use max-width/max-height: 100% for that).
Maximizing the size in these cases should mean:

Portrait: the height of the image = the height of the window. the image is absolutely centered and the infoboxes hug the image on either side.

Landscape: the width of the gallery info box + the width of the image + the width of the the info table = width of the window (In my mind this would just be a natural consequence of the rule for portraits but that might be incorrect)

```html
<!-- the server side rendering here is from Golang templating, the curly braces are not React or Vue or something -->
<!-- you can just ignore the curly braces if you want, but assume gi is gallery index, g is gallery, p is photo, pi is photo index. this entire block exists inside a loop that loops over galleries -->
<!-- the only parent classes/ids for this block are #body and .img-grid -->
               <div class="lbox" id="lbox-{{$gi}}" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="prev" onclick="changeSlide({{$gi}}, -1)"><<</div><div class="next" onclick="changeSlide({{$gi}}, 1)">>></div>
                    <div class="infobox gal-info">
                        <span class="description">
                            {{ $g.Description }}
                        </span>
                        <span class="gallery-upload-stamp">
                            {{ $g.Uploaded }}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    {{range $pi, $p := $g.Photos}} <!-- loop photos in a gallery -->
                        <span class="slide" id="slide-{{$gi}}:{{$pi}}">
                            <img src="{{ $p.Reference }}" class="photo">
                            <table class="infobox img-exif">
                                {{range $k, $v := $p.Exif}}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$k}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$v}}<td>
                                </tr>
                                {{end}}
                            </table>
                        </span>
                    {{end}}
                    
                    
                </div>
```

These are all the rules I use (incl. irrelevant ones, in case there may be an error creating a conflict. I am not a front end developer. If you were to point at a rule and ask "why is that there?" for the most part the answer is "I don't know. Throwing stuff at the wall to see what works. sometimes I forget to clean the wall.")

```css
#body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 90rem;
}

#img-grid {
    max-width: 90rem;
    display: table;
    height: auto;
    outline: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.lbox {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.lbox img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    #vertical-align: top;
}

.prev, .next {
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 25%;
}

.infobox {
    background-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
}

.img-exif {
    position: absolute;
}

.gal-info {
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 500px;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Right now it looks something like this
[image: preview of css]
As you can tell, the image is not centered and the left column takes up a lot of space on screen.
If you were to resize the window, as the image scales down it recesses, creating more space on both sides, which would be fine if it were centered.

Comment: From what I see I think it's a width/height issue that causes the image to get out of its container. Have you tried using `width: 100%` for the image specifically?

Comment: You have to put the buttons and the galery info in a container div since they are actually side by side. If you want the space on the left side of the image as big as the right side, then the buttons should be below gal-info and the new container div should have the same width like img-exif. But without #body and .img-grid in your code snippet it is just guessing what it could be. By the way, delete the irrelevant css info since the three elements do not effect the shown snippet...

Comment: From the html code that you provided, is the right div (details of image like the date taken, iso, lens and etc.) included on the screenshot that you posted?

Comment: The details of the image (in the up right corner of the screenshot) are equivalent to the ```<table class="infobox img-exif">``` from the html snippet...

Answer (score 0):

I'd put another container around all elements for more convenience when positioning them. Also, i'd put the nav arrows below the description to not have another "column" to deal with when centering.

```css
#body {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 90rem;
}

.lbox {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  
  /* These lines actually center the .container */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  /* only for debugging */ 
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Another box around the arrow elements makes it easier to handle them as a group */
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.lbox img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.prev,
.next {
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  background-color: black;
}

.infobox {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-exif {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.gal-info {
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 500px;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="lbox">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="prev" onclick="changeSlide(2, -1)">&lt;&lt;</div>
          <div class="next" onclick="changeSlide(2, 1)">&gt;&gt;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="infobox gal-info">
        <span class="description">
          Description is here
        </span>
        <span class="gallery-upload-stamp">
          Date uploaded is here
        </span>
      </div><!--
   --><span class="slide" id="slide-2:3"><!--
     --><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" class="photo"><!--
     --><table class="infobox img-exif">
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
```

You'll notice the Html comments (`<!-- -->`) around some of the elements. These are to prevent whitespace from separating elements to appear side by side (without them, a little space is always left between inline or inline-block elements next to each other).